# Unknown username or bad password, LDAP Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to authenticate against AD using application mode (ADAM), but keep getting unknown username or bad password. If I test the login in `LDP.exe` it logs in no problem, on simple bind. I've trawled through all similar posts with the same issue, but have not resolved it, any suggestions what I should be checking for?

```
private bool ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(string Username, string Password)
{
   bool Success = false;

   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry Entry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:389/OU=Users,O=TestDirectory", Username, Password);
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher Searcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(Entry);
   Searcher.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;

   try
   {
      System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult Results = Searcher.FindOne();
      Success = (Results != null);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Success = false;
      throw;
   }
   return Success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine what context your application is hitting AD with. If your ASP.NET application pool identity is one that is low privileged, it won't have enough permissions to query active directory. If you don't want to create a custom user to run the app pool as with appropriate permissions - you could use the [LogonUser API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make your ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin call under the  security context of that account.

Finally, you should consider using [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) if you are using .NET 3.5 or above.

You can use code like

```
bool validCreds = false;
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
 {
     validCreds = context.ValidateCredentials( username, password );
 }
```

Comment: I've tried both context's, directoryentry and principal - both with same results, principal using ContextType.ApplicationDirectory as it's ADAM. I've got the app pool as ApplicationPoolIdentity, I tried using Localservice, Localsystem, but get the same error.

Comment: Just for kicks, have you tried adding identity impersonate=true in the web.config, that will execute the request under the context of the requesting user, if that works, perms is the problem.

Comment: Tried <identity impersonate="true">, no effect, issue still exists. I've got the userprincipalname set in AD, If I make a new site in VS and change the membership provider to AD it works no problems, but not from the code as above.

Comment: So you're running the app locally correct? What OS? Win 7? Win2k3/8?

Comment: yeah local, Win7, using local AD.

Comment: I notice in the event log, under the failed login attempt, under "Account Whose Credentials Were Used:" it's got "Account name" as the correct username, but under "Account Domain" theres' nothing - it's blank. However under "subject" at the top, it's got the account domain as IIS APPPOOL.